# Why vlc is giving current time of last frame (get_time())more than that of the total length of the video? (python-vlc)

Tags: python, vlc

Please be noted that when the video is played using python vlc and tried to display the respective time. total length of the video and the current time I am getting for the last frame will vary each time it will either be greater or lesser than that of the actual length of the video.

I tried with python-vlc library.
I want to fetch the exact time of the media player(in mili seconds)

Comment: I genuinely don't think you will get an accurate length, in milliseconds out of vlc or probably any other player, no matter what they report. Vlc.py (vlc) can take a while to settle on what it thinks the actual runtime is. The reported length will vary for the first few seconds of play, until it does settle on a value. If you want a consistent time from the start, you may be better off quizzing the video file itself, with something like `ffprobe`.

Comment: Not the total length of the video, I am asking about the playback time which we get from player.get_time()

Comment: As I stated, python-vlc simply isn't accurate to a millisecond level, `in my experience`. The best you can hope for is about 1/4 of a second. Try printing out the current time in a play loop, you soon notice a pattern, of 4 to 5 timestamps per second. Whilst I appreciate that having millisecond timings are sexy, you rarely need such precision. If you do, you'll need to use an audio/video player other than vlc.

Comment: Can you please explain me more on why this is not possible? And did you mean audio/video player app?

Comment: As I said, run your code printing `player.get_time()` with no sleeps in the play loop, you get lots of duplicate times and then a jump of about a quarter of a second later. It's a restriction, don't why, built in to the vlc/vlc.py code. They probably also thought that that amount of precision was sufficient for playing a video.

Comment: I have observed that, thank you for your support.